# Redirect error 404 Angular 5

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404

I am trying to handle 404 error when urls are wrong, http://localhost:8100/#/login. This is my login url and if I write something like http:.../loginasdasd i would like to automatically open my own NotFoundPage.

```
const appRoutes3: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
         path: 'login',
         component: LoginPage
      },
      { path: 'login**', redirectTo: '/notfound' }
   ]
 },
 { path: 'notfound', component: NotFoundPage }
];


RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes3,
  { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
)
,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
  links: [
    { component: HomePage, name: "Home", segment: "" },
    { component: LoginPage, name: "Login", segment: "login", defaultHistory: [HomePage] },
    { component: SubscribePage, name: "Signup", segment: "signup", defaultHistory: [HomePage] },
    { component: SubscribeExtendPage, name: "Signup", segment: "signup-extend", defaultHistory: [HomePage] },
    { component: MainPage, name: "Main", segment: "main", defaultHistory: [HomePage] },
    { component: WelcomePage, name: "Welcome", segment: "welcome" },
    { component: NotFoundPage, name: "notFound", segment: "login/**", defaultHistory: [HomePage] },
  ]
}
)
],
```

I am an angular noob and I don't how to properly do it, the best info i've found is https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-understanding-redirects-2826177761fc in some other angular redirection posts.

Please some help or any clue would be grateful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a wild character (**). The ** path should be last route. The router will select this route if the requested URL doesn't match any paths for routes defined in the configuration. This is useful for displaying a "404 - Not Found" page or redirecting to another route.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
   path: 'heroes',
   component: HeroListComponent,
 data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
 },
 {  path: '',
 redirectTo: '/heroes',
 pathMatch: 'full'
 },
 { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As Angular tries to match the routes in the order you declared in your Routes array. You could do this:

```
const appRoutes3: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
         path: 'login',
         component: LoginPage
      }
 },
 { path: '**', component: NotFoundPage }
];
```

But if you really want a route `/notfound`, change the `redirectTo: '/notfound'` for `redirectTo: 'notfound'`.

Answer (score 1):

Below code working fine in my case,

```
{ path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

Add below code in your app.component.ts

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.errorHandler = (error: any) => {
        let routerError = error.toString();
        if (routerError.indexOf('Cannot match any routes') >= 0 ) {
           this.router.navigate(['/404']);
        } else {
           throw error;
        }
    }
  }
```